# I need to implement both a onSeekBarChangeListener and an OnClickListerner

Tags: android, textview, seekbar

I am not sure if i need two classes or not, if I do I need to know how to pass data from one class to another and if not I need to know how to add an onClickListener to a class that already implements onSeekBarChangeListener.
Here's what I have so far:

```
    package com.codeherenow.sicalculator;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;

    public class SICalculatorActivity extends Activity implements   SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
    private int years;
    private TextView YT;
    private SeekBar bar;
    private EditText principal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PA_field);
    private EditText interest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IR_field);
    public EditText pvalue;
    public EditText ivalue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);
    bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    pvalue = (EditText) principal.getText();
    ivalue = (EditText) interest.getText();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int i, boolean b){
        years = i;
        YT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
        YT.setText(years + " Year(s)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){

    }

}
```

Comment: What issues are you having? You should be able to just go `implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, View.OnClickListener`

Comment: @PaulThompson that's what I didn't know, how to add two implements on the top, thanks for your example

Comment: I'll put it as an answer if that was your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a comma between all interfaces that you are implementing. In this case you'd need to have

```
public class SICalculatorActivity extends Activity 
       implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, View.OnClickListener{
```

You can continue using this method to implement any number of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement as many interfaces as you need:

```
public class SICalculatorActivity extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private int years;
    private TextView YT;
    private SeekBar bar;
    private EditText principal;
    private EditText interest;
    public EditText pvalue;
    public EditText ivalue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);

    //should init here to avoid NullPointerException
        principal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PA_field);
        interest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IR_field);

        bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

//      set click listener -  someView.setOnClickListener(this);

        pvalue = (EditText) principal.getText();
        ivalue = (EditText) interest.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
//            case R.id.someViewId:
                //handle click
//                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int i, boolean b){
        years = i;
        YT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
        YT.setText(years + " Year(s)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){

    }
}
```